# Network problem with my Lumia 535

Tags: windows-10-mobile, settings, nokia-lumia-535, cellular-data

My Lumia 535 running Windows 10 Mobile has a network problem. I can't lock or force to 3G-only mode. Is there any way to lock 3G-only mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the highest connection speed your phone uses for mobile data, follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings → Network & wireless → Cellular & SIM (or Mobile & SIM)
2. Tap on "SIM settings"

   - on a dual-SIM phone, tap "SIM 1 settings" or "SIM 2 settings", depending on which SIM card you've set to be used for mobile data
3. Change the "Highest connection speed" setting to your liking. One of the options should be "3G only", which I understand is what you're looking for.

For more information about SIM settings in Windows 10 Mobile, see [this support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10744/windows-10-mobile-cellular-sim-settings).

Comment: But i can't lock on 3g only mode

Comment: What do you mean "can't lock on"? Did you find the setting I mentioned? Is "3G only" one of the options? Does it work as the name would imply?

Comment: 3g only mode is not in my phone